# Break links for workbook not breaking every link?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to break external workbook links with a for each loop, but it seems to not be working when I reopen the new file; I noticed that every iteration results in the external links popup.

What am I doing wrong? `wbkTarget` is the new workbook that I housed the sheets from an external wb.

```
Dim link As Variant: link = wbkTarget.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
If Not IsEmpty(wbkTarget.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
    For Each link In wbkTarget.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        wbkTarget.BreakLink link, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next link
End If
```

Comment: Are those other links of a different type like OLE or on MAC?

Comment: On PC, and I don't think they're an OLE type

Comment: You can try the same loop on the `xlOLELinks`

Comment: [This helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337861/removing-external-links)?

Comment: @BigBen your answer, and that one above, are still prompting link updates when I open the new wb after saving

Comment: @BigBen I think I may have found the issue, I password protect all sheets before doing this. I noticed that the `break links` prompt in the data ribbon was greyed out.